# 404 NotFound with HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient class (from namespace System.Net.Http) to POST data to an asp.net Web API action in a Windows form application.  My problem is I keep receiving **Status Code 404 Not Found** (Endpoint not found).  Am I missing something?  Please help.  Thank you in advance.

The following is my C# code that uses HttpClient to make a POST request to XML Web API:

```
private async Task PostCustomForm()
        {

            using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {
                NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

                try
                {
                    CustomFormLog customFormLog = new CustomFormLog();
                    customFormLog.DeviceId = 1234;
                    customFormLog.UserExperienceId = 33442036854775807;
                    customFormLog.NetworkItemId = 58595555;


                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xyzwebserver/");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync<CustomFormLog>("logdata/customform/1234", customFormLog); 



                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        logger.Info(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.Info(response);

                    }
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    logger.Error(ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

And following is the **help** text from that XML Web API web stie:

```
Url: http://xyzwebserver/logdata/customform?device={DEVICEID}

HTTP Method: POST

Message direction   Format  Body
Request Xml Example,Schema
Response    N/A The Response body is empty.
The following is an example request Xml body:

<CustomFormLog>
  <OptIn>true</OptIn>
  <UserExperienceId>3372036854775807</UserExperienceId>
  <NetworkItemId>64093484</NetworkItemId>
  <FormData />
</CustomFormLog>
The following is the request Xml Schema:

<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="CustomFormLog" nillable="true" type="CustomFormLog" />
  <xs:complexType name="CustomFormLog">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OptIn" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="UserExperienceId" type="xs:long" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NetworkItemId" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FormData">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="lax" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Finally, My custom DTO class:

```
public class CustomFormLog
    {
        public int DeviceId { get; set; }
        public bool OptIn { get;set;}
        public long UserExperienceId { get; set; }
        public int NetworkItemId { get; set; }


        public XElement FormData { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Waht does ur controller and route config looks like

Comment: @Guanxi, unfortunately, I do not own that web API.  I just base on the help text from that web API provider site only. Please see my post for such a HELP Web API text I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so from the help information it seems the URL that is expcted is

```
Url: http://xyzwebserver/logdata/customform?device={DEVICEID}
```

but what you are sending is

```
Url: http://xyzwebserver/logdata/customform/1234
```

this wont turn up to correct URL until the web api route config has {device} defined in their Route config. I would suggest use their mentioned format for url and change Requesting line to

```
HttpResponseMessage response = 
await client.PostAsXmlAsync<CustomFormLog>("logdata/customform?device=1234", customFormLog);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I follow your suggestion.  And the error "404 NotFound" is gone.   But, I got another error like -- StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Wed, 10 Sep 2014 20:56:35 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 1758
  Content-Type: text/html
}

Comment: This is request specific error they might be having some sort of validation that is failing and that's why you are getting that error. The only guess I can make from the help text is that they are not expecting DeviceID in the CustomFormLog class. give it a try, but other then that I don't think I can suggest anything without knowing the Service.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I remove property "DeviceId" from DTO class CustomFormLog, but the StatusCode 400 BadRequest persists. I guess, the WEB API service action validate the DeviceId parameter. Anyway, thank you for your help. By the way, do you know what online resources/articles/blogs so I can read to learn more about the meanings and rules of a HELP text from Web API site in general?

Comment: I haven't gone through any :( you can try asp.net site. You can mark it as answered (as it solved the original problem)

Answer (score 0):

Check your route.config file, you are probably not directing to the controller.  I can't say for sure what it should be because you haven't posted the config file.  Something to be aware of if you are using the default web API template there will be two route config files, one for the api controllers and one for the basic controllers.  My guess would be that your controller has the default /api/ in it's route.  In that case the fix to your problem would be

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync<CustomFormLog>("api/logdata/customform/1234", customFormLog);
```

Comment: unfortunately, I do not own that web API.  I just base on the help text from that web API provider site only. Please see my post for such a HELP Web API text I got.  From the HELP text from that web API site, I need to pass deviceId parameter in request URL query string and XML object in request XML body.